# Can Backbone and Express routers work together in an Express application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I have built several Backbone apps and appreciate the client-side code structure and organization. I'm moving into Node development, using Express, and I'm uncertain as to how Express and Backbone can work together in the handling of routes.

Comment: Backbone.Router is for client-side routing, ie: using the html5 history API to change the URL when you update the page via ajax.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that Node and Backbone are independent from each other.

- **Node** is for server-side (e.g working with a database, api serving etc. ) .
- **Backbone** is a client-side Javascript MVC framework which gives you a structure for organizing your client-side Javascript application. (the application in the browser)

You can have a Backbone application in your client-side and it can hook up to any back-end either Node, Rails, PHP etc...

For more info check MVVM pattern and Javascript frameworks on the client-side.

http://backbonetutorials.com/why-would-you-use-backbone/

http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/

Comment: you could use Backbone models and collections, and views and events on the back-end side, and probably even the router with some adjustments

Comment: That's correct.I just gave simple info for the question asker to understand the concept first.

Comment: Thanks Serdar, I forgot to explain that I am using Express. I have a strong understanding of Backbone and client-side JavaScript. What I am not sure of is how Express routing and Backbone routing can coexist. In a Backbone app, I would write it so that if a visitor navigates to /foo the foo path would be in my router and execute a function that would generate Backbone models and views. However, in an Express app, Express wants to handle this routing and run it's own function(req, res). Can these work together or do I have to choose one?

Comment: You can use them both. You'll keep using Backbone on the client side. Express is concerned with the server side. On Express you are defining what is it that the SERVER should do once a request /foo or /bar make it to the server.

Comment: Thanks Hector. A friend pointed out to me something that I was forgetting. Backbone uses hash links, so a Backbone route would be /#foo and the Express route would be /foo. The first would run the Backbone route's respective function in the client and the second would run the function on the server. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 2):

A friend gave me the answer:

Backbone uses hash routes. For instance http://yoursite.com/#foo

Express will use the traditional http://yoursite.com/foo

You can use the routers independent of one another based one which address you path to - a hash route for client-side functions and the traditional route for server side functionality.

Both routers can coexist.

Answer (score 1):

Your question on how Backbone and Express can work together cannot really be answered precisely, because there are really countless ways on which they can work together. Hopefully some of the info below can help you do what you want to do.

First of all, you *can* use www.example.com/foo (no #) routes on the client side (Backbone) - see the `pushState` option in [Backbone.history.start()](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start) documentation. It is possible to integrate the routes on the client side and on the server side. It is not easy to find exactly how to do, though.

Some of the info under those links may help you:

- https://github.com/developmentseed/bones
- https://github.com/SC5/backbone-serverside
- https://github.com/tysoncadenhead/backbone-on-express
- http://nerds.airbnb.com/weve-launched-our-first-nodejs-app-to-product
- http://blog.andyet.com/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/

You wrote that you have experience with Backbone but you're moving to Node recently so I assume that you are open to other frameworks than only Express. You may consider using eg. [restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/) (in addition to Express) to make a RESTful service which you can integrate with Backbone.

There are also entire frameworks like [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) or [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) that cover both client side and server side using one code base and you can share much more than just the routers.

(Also, I've just found this year's (2013) HTML5DevConf talk: [Surviving Robots and Old Browsers by Server-side Backbone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfXneZ89FY0). I haven't watched it yet but it seems very relevant to your problem.)